# Why my BroadcastReceiver is geting unregisted when my app runs in background?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I register a BroadcastReceiver in my activity to handle broadcast that it send by a GCMBaseIntentService when a message is arrived.When my app runs in foregound everything works fine but after a long time in backround even if I dont unregister receiver my activity dont work properly(dont receive the broadcast).How can I resolve that?

Becasuse it is my first time using BroadcastReceiver this is my code:

```
<receiver
     android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <category android:name="dim.taxigen.taxigen_driver"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

In manifest.

```
registerReceiver(mreceiver, new IntentFilter(
             "dim.taxigen.taxigen_driver.DISPLAY_MESSAGE"));
```

and how i register in my Activity.

Comment: How about you show us some relevant bits of code.

Comment: Whilst testing ensure that your server does not set the message parameters delay_while_idle and time_to_live. This way they will take on their default values of false and 4 weeks respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't declare your `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest but programmatically. That is most likely your problem, because if your app is in the background it may get killed at any moment when memory gets low. The longer it is in the background, the bigger is the chance that it gets killed.

You can declare your `BroadcastReceiver` in xml like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.Receiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            ... // Put the broadcasts you want to receive here
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Just put that in the application tag in your manifest.

Comment: Then what do you mean by "even if I dont unregister receiver". Please show us relevant code and your manifest.

Comment: Ok and which receiver is it exactly that is making problems? if it's the one you registered programmatically then I can tell you why: Because you did not declare it in your manifest.

Comment: So..The receiver i declare to manifest is for my gcmservice and i have to declare the mreceiver too?Am I right?

Comment: Yes if you want it to receive all the time than you have to declare it in your manifest. If you register a receiver programmatically it is only receiving as long as you app is running.

Comment: Sorry if my questions are silly!If I declare the receiver in manifest I have to remove the register() from my activity or I keep it and unregister() it propertly in on destroy?

Comment: No you don't have to do anything in code. Just put the `<receiver />` tag in your manifest and that's it. You don't have to register or unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity, when `onStop()` / `onPause()` gets called you should remove the broadcast, because if your app runs on background for a long period of time your `Activity` is likely to be destroyed.

If you want always your app to receive a broadcast, you should register a receiver object in your manifest.

Something like:

```
<receiver android:name="com.smm.receivers.NewMessageReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.smm.action.message_received" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And then create an object called `NewMessageReceiver` in your application which will handle always your broadcast.

Hope it helps